# Search Center: How do you re-order the tabs

Tags: search

Context: SP 2010, Enterprise Search center site.

How do you re-order the tabs on the search + result pages?

I've found [documentation for how its done in SP 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857480.aspx) but SP 2010 seems to have removed the "Change Item Order" option.

Comment: Right now, it seems like the only way to control the order of display requires deleting and re-creating them in the order the order you want them to display. ie: you have 6 tabs: {a,b,f,c,d,e}. To put them in alphabetical order you must delete f,c,d and e and re-create them in this order: c,d,e,f

Comment: I didn't find a better way than deleting all entries and recreating them in the desired order. But I did find it really easy using the Datasheet View and MS Excel: View the list in Datasheet View, cut all contents, paste to Excel, reorder rows, paste back into Datasheet View, switch back to Standard View. I immediately tested my results pages and the tabs were reordered correctly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has responded and from everything I've seen it seems like there's no 'built in' way to do this I'm going to mark this as answered.  And the 'answer' is: you must delete the incorrectly ordered tabs and then re-create them in the order you want.  If anyone knows a better way, please feel free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 5):

yeah can do it.

Need to open the list, then manully change the URL to 'reorder.aspx' instead of 'listedit.aspx' - see [this link](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/09/09/getting-started-with-search-results/).

Comment: This is great, haven't realized you can reorder tabs without deleting and recreating the list items in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily changed the tab order for your subsites in SharePoint 2010. 
1. Go to Site Actions/Site Settings
2. Under Look and Feel, click Top Link Bar
3. Reorder.

I believe this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this, I edited the web part, went to layout, and used the Zone Index. I am using EasyTabs. Once I ordered the Zone Indexes, they appeared as I hoped.